# AS3 - iOS app crashes at breakpoint

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, segmentation-fault, breakpoints

I have a very annoying problem with debugging AIR apps on iOS devices and simulators.

Simply put, the app crashes when I'm debugging application and it stops at a breakpoint. Then the line with breakpoint is selected for a second or less and then the app is gone.

Here's some logs I got from simulator after last flash trace:

> assertiond[30178]: assertion failed: 15G31 13E230: assertiond + 16726 [1BD9E3D0-5485-3412-86B2-4BE50C825E80]: 0x1
>
> SpringBoard[30174]: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
>
> SpringBoard[30174]: BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection invalid
>
> --- last message repeated 1 time ---
>
> com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.EE317320-40C9-4513-9BE9-02611D6DD722.launchd_sim[30158] (UIKitApplication:com.my.app.id[0x31d1][30651]): Service exited due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
>
> assertiond[30178]: assertion failed: 15G31 13E230: assertiond + 16726 [1BD9E3D0-5485-3412-86B2-4BE50C825E80]: 0x1
>
> SpringBoard[30174]: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.my.app.id[0x31d1]' crashed.
>
> assertiond[30178]: assertion failed: 15G31 13E230: assertiond + 16726 [1BD9E3D0-5485-3412-86B2-4BE50C825E80]: 0x1
>
> assertiond[30178]: notify_suspend_pid() failed with error 7

And that's it.

The funny thing is that it may not happen for months, then suddenly every breakpoint causes a crash.

From what I've noticed, the device, iOS version, and AIR version don't matter.

Have you guys ever faced this problem? Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: What SDK are you using? try different ones

Comment: Yes, I've tried different SDKs, no luck there

Answer (score 0):

The AIR compiler has a known issue in the following scenarios:

> If the base class function doesn't use any arguments and the overridden function in the derived class does, then any function calls through the base class reference can cause the application to terminate abruptly.

If 32-bit support is required, downgrading may be required:

> However, with the release of AIR 20, only a 64-bit Runtime dynamic Library is provided on Mac OS X. See AIR 20 release notes for details.
>
> Certain users who are running apps that require 32-bit ANEs may want to downgrade to a lower AIR version that supports a 32-bit Runtime dynamic Library.

The Flash Debugger(fdb) combined with the AIR Debug Launcher(ADL) may give more information:

> Use the AIR Debug Launcher (ADL) to run both SWF-based and HTML-based applications during development. Using ADL, you can run an application without first packaging and installing it. By default, ADL uses a runtime included with the SDK, which means you do not have to install the runtime separately to use ADL.
>
> AIR supports debugging directly, so you do not need a debug version of the runtime (as you would with Adobe® Flash® Player). To conduct command-line debugging, you use the Flash Debugger and the AIR Debug Launcher (ADL).
>
> The Flash Debugger is distributed in the Flex SDK directory. The native versions, such as fdb.exe on Windows, are in the bin subdirectory. The Java version is in the lib subdirectory. The AIR Debug Launcher, adl.exe, is in the bin directory of your Flex SDK installation. (There is no separate Java version).
>
> Note: You cannot start an AIR application directly with fdb, because fdb attempts to launch it with Flash Player. Instead, let the AIR application connect to a running fdb session.

**References**

- [AIR Compiler Known Issues](https://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/air-compiler-known-issues.html)
- [Building Adobe AIR Applications: AIR Debug Launcher (ADL)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-6fa6d7e0128cca93d31-8000.html)
- [Debugging with fdb](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/Mustella+Overview#MustellaOverview-DebuggingwithFDB)
- [Issues while downgrading from AIR 20 to a lower version on Mac OS X](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2015/12/issues-downgrading-from-air-20-mac.html)
- [AIR 20 Release Notes](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/fp_20_air_20_release_notes.html)
- [Archived Adobe AIR SDK versions](https://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/archived-air-sdk-version.html)
- [Troubleshoot Adobe AIR installation for Mac OS](https://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/troubleshoot-air-installation-mac-os.html)